# ¿Como recorrer una lista list<employees> que dentro de si puede tener 1 o mas listas del mismo tipo list<employees>?

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista List, la cual puede tener dentro de si mismo una o varias listas del mismo tipo List,necesito imprimir todo en pantalla, es decir, imprimir toda la información de todos los nodos hijos, según lo que he investigado se podria hacer recursivamente pero no lo he logrado, por favor HELP.
Ejemplo Lista de Empleados:

```
 private static List<Employees> GetEmployees()
    {
        List<Employees> lstEmployees = new List<Employees>();

        Employees objEmployees1 = new Employees()
        {
            Name = "Wilmar",
            Position = "Manager",
            Subordinates = new List<Employees>
            {
               new Employees 
               {
                   Name = "Juan",
                   Position = "Sub Manager" ,
                   Subordinates = new List<Employees>
                   {
                       new Employees
                       {
                            Name = "Richard",
                            Position = "Sub-Secretary Manager",
                            Subordinates = new List<Employees>
                            {
                                new Employees
                                {
                                    Name = "Richard",
                                    Position = "Sub-Secretary Manager"
                                }
                            }
                       }
                   }
               },
               new Employees 
               {
                   Name = "Laura",
                   Position = "TM" 
               },
               new Employees 
               { 
                   Name = "Marcela",
                   Position = "LT" 
               }
            }
        };

        lstEmployees.Add(objEmployees1);

        Employees objEmployees2 = new Employees()
        {
            Name = "Lorena",
            Position = "CEO",
            Subordinates = new List<Employees>
            {
               new Employees { Name = "Juana",Position = "Sub CEO" },
               new Employees { Name = "Camila",Position = "Sub TM" },
               new Employees { Name = "Marcelinha",Position = "Sub LT" }
            }
        };

        lstEmployees.Add(objEmployees2);
        return lstEmployees;
    }
```

Intente hacerlo con For y ForEach pero alli tendria que saber exactamente cuantos nodos se tiene en la lista, lo cual no se podria determinar, es por esto que se debe hacer recursivamente, les agradeceria demasiado lacolaboración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Método recursivo:

```
static void Print(List<Employees> employees, int level){

    employees?.ForEach(e => {

          // imprimir los datos de este employee
          Console.WriteLine($"{Padding()}name: {e.Name}");
          Console.WriteLine($"{Padding()}position: {e.Position}");
          Console.WriteLine($"{Padding()}subordinates: ");

          // llamada recursiva para imprimir los subordinates de este employee
          // el nivel se incrementa en uno para distinguir el nivel de anidamiento
          Print(e.Subordinates, level + 1);

    });
    
    // método auxiliar para agregar tabulaciones para distinguir los niveles
     string Padding(){
        return string.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat<string>("\t", level).ToArray());
      }

  }
```

Llamada al método:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {

    var employees = GetEmployees();

    Print(employees,0);

  }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funcionó de maravilla